# What is the mathematical role of the Factor attribute in the mix color node?

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes, procedural

I am trying to figure exactly how, on a mathematical level, the *Factor* attribute influences the operations of the *Mix Color Node* in blender.
Say for example you use the *Color Burn* operation.
The mathematical formula for this is

$Color_{burn} = 1 - \frac{1 - Color_1}{ Color_2}$

So for example if input $Color_1$ has an R-channel value of $0.6$ and input $Color_2$ has an R-channel value of $0.5$, the resulting $Color_{burn}$ with a *Factor* attribute set to $1$ comes out to an R-channel value of

$1 - \frac{1 - 0.6}{0.5} = 0.2$

So far so good I understand what's happening.

However, if I set the *Factor* attribute to, say, $0.5$, I get a resulting R-channel value of $0.468$ and I don't understand why.

What, mathematically speaking, is the *Factor* attribute doing??

Comment: I just tested it in the compositor and got a very slightly different result of 0.46 repeating, which is 7/15 if that helps out.

Comment: Looking at the [source code of the mix fucntion](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/main/source/blender/blenlib/BLI_color_mix.hh) in line 937, it seems to rely on a variable `Traits:range`, which I haven't been able to track down.

Comment: @JonasGörke the definition of `range` is `1.0`, here https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/main/source/blender/blenlib/BLI_color_mix.hh#L60

Answer (score 14):

$$Color_{burn} = 1 - \frac{1 - Color_1}{1 - Fac + Fac \cdot Color_2}$$
$$0 \leq Color_{burn} \leq 1$$

The osl source you can find in `Source\blender-3.x.x\intern\cycles\kernel\osl\shaders` The source code of the mix color node is as follows

```
/* SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 * Copyright 2011-2022 Blender Foundation */

#include "node_color.h"
#include "node_color_blend.h"
#include "stdcycles.h"

shader node_mix_color(string blend_type = "mix",
                      int use_clamp = 0,
                      int use_clamp_result = 0,
                      float Factor = 0.5,
                      color A = 0.0,
                      color B = 0.0,
                      output color Result = 0.0)
{
  float t = (use_clamp) ? clamp(Factor, 0.0, 1.0) : Factor;

  if (blend_type == "mix")
    Result = mix(A, B, t);
  if (blend_type == "add")
    Result = node_mix_add(t, A, B);
  if (blend_type == "multiply")
    Result = node_mix_mul(t, A, B);
  if (blend_type == "screen")
    Result = node_mix_screen(t, A, B);
  if (blend_type == "overlay")
    Result = node_mix_overlay(t, A, B);
  if (blend_type == "subtract")
    Result = node_mix_sub(t, A, B);
  if (blend_type == "divide")
    Result = node_mix_div(t, A, B);
  if (blend_type == "difference")
    Result = node_mix_diff(t, A, B);
  if (blend_type == "darken")
    Result = node_mix_dark(t, A, B);
  if (blend_type == "lighten")
    Result = node_mix_light(t, A, B);
  if (blend_type == "dodge")
    Result = node_mix_dodge(t, A, B);
  if (blend_type == "burn")
    Result = node_mix_burn(t, A, B);
  if (blend_type == "hue")
    Result = node_mix_hue(t, A, B);
  if (blend_type == "saturation")
    Result = node_mix_sat(t, A, B);
  if (blend_type == "value")
    Result = node_mix_val(t, A, B);
  if (blend_type == "color")
    Result = node_mix_color(t, A, B);
  if (blend_type == "soft_light")
    Result = node_mix_soft(t, A, B);
  if (blend_type == "linear_light")
    Result = node_mix_linear(t, A, B);

  if (use_clamp_result)
    Result = clamp(Result, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

For the function definition, you can look at `node_color_blend.h` in the same directory

```
/* SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 * Copyright 2011-2022 Blender Foundation */

color node_mix_blend(float t, color col1, color col2)
{
  return mix(col1, col2, t);
}

color node_mix_add(float t, color col1, color col2)
{
  return mix(col1, col1 + col2, t);
}

color node_mix_mul(float t, color col1, color col2)
{
  return mix(col1, col1 * col2, t);
}

color node_mix_screen(float t, color col1, color col2)
{
  float tm = 1.0 - t;

  return color(1.0) - (color(tm) + t * (color(1.0) - col2)) * (color(1.0) - col1);
}

color node_mix_overlay(float t, color col1, color col2)
{
  float tm = 1.0 - t;

  color outcol = col1;

  if (outcol[0] < 0.5)
    outcol[0] *= tm + 2.0 * t * col2[0];
  else
    outcol[0] = 1.0 - (tm + 2.0 * t * (1.0 - col2[0])) * (1.0 - outcol[0]);

  if (outcol[1] < 0.5)
    outcol[1] *= tm + 2.0 * t * col2[1];
  else
    outcol[1] = 1.0 - (tm + 2.0 * t * (1.0 - col2[1])) * (1.0 - outcol[1]);

  if (outcol[2] < 0.5)
    outcol[2] *= tm + 2.0 * t * col2[2];
  else
    outcol[2] = 1.0 - (tm + 2.0 * t * (1.0 - col2[2])) * (1.0 - outcol[2]);

  return outcol;
}

color node_mix_sub(float t, color col1, color col2)
{
  return mix(col1, col1 - col2, t);
}

color node_mix_div(float t, color col1, color col2)
{
  float tm = 1.0 - t;

  color outcol = col1;

  if (col2[0] != 0.0)
    outcol[0] = tm * outcol[0] + t * outcol[0] / col2[0];
  if (col2[1] != 0.0)
    outcol[1] = tm * outcol[1] + t * outcol[1] / col2[1];
  if (col2[2] != 0.0)
    outcol[2] = tm * outcol[2] + t * outcol[2] / col2[2];

  return outcol;
}

color node_mix_diff(float t, color col1, color col2)
{
  return mix(col1, abs(col1 - col2), t);
}

color node_mix_dark(float t, color col1, color col2)
{
  return mix(col1, min(col1, col2), t);
}

color node_mix_light(float t, color col1, color col2)
{
  return mix(col1, max(col1, col2), t);
}

color node_mix_dodge(float t, color col1, color col2)
{
  color outcol = col1;

  if (outcol[0] != 0.0) {
    float tmp = 1.0 - t * col2[0];
    if (tmp <= 0.0)
      outcol[0] = 1.0;
    else if ((tmp = outcol[0] / tmp) > 1.0)
      outcol[0] = 1.0;
    else
      outcol[0] = tmp;
  }
  if (outcol[1] != 0.0) {
    float tmp = 1.0 - t * col2[1];
    if (tmp <= 0.0)
      outcol[1] = 1.0;
    else if ((tmp = outcol[1] / tmp) > 1.0)
      outcol[1] = 1.0;
    else
      outcol[1] = tmp;
  }
  if (outcol[2] != 0.0) {
    float tmp = 1.0 - t * col2[2];
    if (tmp <= 0.0)
      outcol[2] = 1.0;
    else if ((tmp = outcol[2] / tmp) > 1.0)
      outcol[2] = 1.0;
    else
      outcol[2] = tmp;
  }

  return outcol;
}

color node_mix_burn(float t, color col1, color col2)
{
  float tmp, tm = 1.0 - t;

  color outcol = col1;

  tmp = tm + t * col2[0];
  if (tmp <= 0.0)
    outcol[0] = 0.0;
  else if ((tmp = (1.0 - (1.0 - outcol[0]) / tmp)) < 0.0)
    outcol[0] = 0.0;
  else if (tmp > 1.0)
    outcol[0] = 1.0;
  else
    outcol[0] = tmp;

  tmp = tm + t * col2[1];
  if (tmp <= 0.0)
    outcol[1] = 0.0;
  else if ((tmp = (1.0 - (1.0 - outcol[1]) / tmp)) < 0.0)
    outcol[1] = 0.0;
  else if (tmp > 1.0)
    outcol[1] = 1.0;
  else
    outcol[1] = tmp;

  tmp = tm + t * col2[2];
  if (tmp <= 0.0)
    outcol[2] = 0.0;
  else if ((tmp = (1.0 - (1.0 - outcol[2]) / tmp)) < 0.0)
    outcol[2] = 0.0;
  else if (tmp > 1.0)
    outcol[2] = 1.0;
  else
    outcol[2] = tmp;

  return outcol;
}

color node_mix_hue(float t, color col1, color col2)
{
  color outcol = col1;
  color hsv2 = rgb_to_hsv(col2);

  if (hsv2[1] != 0.0) {
    color hsv = rgb_to_hsv(outcol);
    hsv[0] = hsv2[0];
    color tmp = hsv_to_rgb(hsv);

    outcol = mix(outcol, tmp, t);
  }

  return outcol;
}

color node_mix_sat(float t, color col1, color col2)
{
  float tm = 1.0 - t;

  color outcol = col1;

  color hsv = rgb_to_hsv(outcol);

  if (hsv[1] != 0.0) {
    color hsv2 = rgb_to_hsv(col2);

    hsv[1] = tm * hsv[1] + t * hsv2[1];
    outcol = hsv_to_rgb(hsv);
  }

  return outcol;
}

color node_mix_val(float t, color col1, color col2)
{
  float tm = 1.0 - t;

  color hsv = rgb_to_hsv(col1);
  color hsv2 = rgb_to_hsv(col2);

  hsv[2] = tm * hsv[2] + t * hsv2[2];

  return hsv_to_rgb(hsv);
}

color node_mix_color(float t, color col1, color col2)
{
  color outcol = col1;
  color hsv2 = rgb_to_hsv(col2);

  if (hsv2[1] != 0.0) {
    color hsv = rgb_to_hsv(outcol);
    hsv[0] = hsv2[0];
    hsv[1] = hsv2[1];
    color tmp = hsv_to_rgb(hsv);

    outcol = mix(outcol, tmp, t);
  }

  return outcol;
}

color node_mix_soft(float t, color col1, color col2)
{
  float tm = 1.0 - t;

  color one = color(1.0);
  color scr = one - (one - col2) * (one - col1);

  return tm * col1 + t * ((one - col1) * col2 * col1 + col1 * scr);
}

color node_mix_linear(float t, color col1, color col2)
{
  color outcol = col1;

  if (col2[0] > 0.5)
    outcol[0] = col1[0] + t * (2.0 * (col2[0] - 0.5));
  else
    outcol[0] = col1[0] + t * (2.0 * (col2[0]) - 1.0);

  if (col2[1] > 0.5)
    outcol[1] = col1[1] + t * (2.0 * (col2[1] - 0.5));
  else
    outcol[1] = col1[1] + t * (2.0 * (col2[1]) - 1.0);

  if (col2[2] > 0.5)
    outcol[2] = col1[2] + t * (2.0 * (col2[2] - 0.5));
  else
    outcol[2] = col1[2] + t * (2.0 * (col2[2]) - 1.0);

  return outcol;
}

color node_mix_clamp(color col)
{
  color outcol = col;

  outcol[0] = clamp(col[0], 0.0, 1.0);
  outcol[1] = clamp(col[1], 0.0, 1.0);
  outcol[2] = clamp(col[2], 0.0, 1.0);

  return outcol;
}
```

Here we see a mix function which the inputs is `col1, col2` and the `factor`
It return `col1 * (1 - factor) + col2 * factor` when no clamp

In your color burn example:

```
col1 = 0.6
col2 = 0.5
factor = 0.5
```

According the `node_mix_burn` function,

```
tm = 1.0 - 0.5      >>>> 0.5
outcol = 0.6

tmp = tm + t * col2     >>>> 0.5 + 0.5 * 0.5  >>>> 0.75

tmp = 1.0 - (1.0 - 0.6) / 0.75  >>>> 0.46666...
```

and it doesn't match the 3 cases, so return 0.46666...

On the other hand, you can make a custom node using osl in cycle
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/osl.html

[image]

```
#include "node_color.h"
#include "node_color_blend.h"
#include "stdcycles.h"

shader my_burn(
                color A = 0.0,
                color B = 0.0,
                float Factor = 0.5,
                output color Result = 0.0    
){
    Result = node_mix_burn(Factor, A, B);
}
```

Comment: Nitpicking, but: `tmp` is uninitialized in the first line of `node_mix_burn` so this line in your explanation `tmp = 1.0 - 0.5     >>>> 0.5` should be removed, it's not correct and confusing. Other than that, great answer!

Comment: Agreed .. :) great stuff.  And a helpful comment, too...

Comment: Perhaps it should be noted for the extract of formulas that at least (I haven't checked all functions yet) for the _Lighten_ blend mode there seems to be an error (or for whatever reason just a different function) in _Geometry Nodes_. The formulas above seem to be from the _Shader Editor_.

Comment: In Blender 3.6, I can't see the Open Shading Language checkbox you boxed in yellow, but I'm still able to create the custom node, so I guess it's no longer needed to tick that box?

Comment: Not sure if it works when the checkbox is not enabled. I noticed that when your device is set to CUDA, the checkbox disappears. I'm currently using 3.61 OptiX and the checkbox is still there.

Comment: Great answer, thank you very much!!

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie The _Open Shading Language_ only appears if you have either set the _Device_ to _CPU_ or to _GPU Compute_ with _OptiX_ enabled. As stated in the manual linked in the answer: _"These nodes will only work with the CPU and OptiX rendering backend."_ It is not necessary to tick the checkbox to **create** such node, but to **use** it. If you disable OSL or render with CUDA, the node will not produce any output. Like nodes only working in _Eevee_ or _Cycles_, Blender allows you to create one material for different engines - would be terrible if nodes disappear when switching engines.